# Extract Named Enities that are listed in dbpedia pages but there is no informatiotion about them

Tags: sparql, dbpedia

I am trying to collect Albums and the list of songs per Album. For example for the Album
[River_of_Tuoni](http://dbpedia.org/page/River_of_Tuoni), the dbpprop:title property provides the list of the songs but only two of them are in DBpedia.
[image]
 so when i do the following query  , I only get two, (My_Only_car,River_of_Tuoni_(song)).

```
SELECT ?songs
WHERE {
   :River_of_Tuoni dbpprop:title ?songs. ?songs a dbpedia-owl:Song .
}
```

How can i get all the songs (Lullaby, Sunrise,...)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> dbpprop:title property provides the list of the songs but only two of
>   them are in DBpedia.

The dbprop:title property doesn't provide any list;  there just happen to be a number of triples with that property.  All the data is in DBpedia;  the values you've shown in the screenshot indicate that two of the values happen to be URIs, while other values happen to be strings.  In general, the data with the dbpprop: properties is "dirtier" than the dbpedia-owl: properties, so getting two different types of values is not very surprising.

The simple query

```
select ?title where {
  dbpedia:River_of_Tuoni dbpprop:title ?title
}
```

[SPARQL results](http://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org&query=select%20%3Ftitle%20where%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20dbpedia%3ARiver_of_Tuoni%20dbpprop%3Atitle%20%3Ftitle%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A&format=text%2Fhtml&timeout=30000&debug=on)

returns all the titles.  However, because the dbpedia-owl: properties have cleaner data, I'd usually suggest that you consider using one of those instead of dbpprop:title, but in this case it doesn't look like there's an alternative.  You might consider this alternate query to get just strings, though:

```
select ?title where {
  dbpedia:River_of_Tuoni (dbpprop:title/rdfs:label)|dbpprop:title ?title
  filter isLiteral(?title)
}
```

[SPARQL results](http://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org&query=select%20%3Ftitle%20where%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20dbpedia%3ARiver_of_Tuoni%20%28dbpprop%3Atitle%2Frdfs%3Alabel%29%7Cdbpprop%3Atitle%20%3Ftitle%0D%0A%20%20filter%20isLiteral%28%3Ftitle%29%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A&format=text%2Fhtml&timeout=30000&debug=on)

For the cases where the value is another resource, taking the rdfs:label of the resource provides a string.  (I *think* that this should also be achievable with `dbprop:title/(rdfs:label?)`, but that doesn't work with the DBpedia endpoint.)

Comment: I edited my question adding my query, now I can see the problem, it was my fault. Great comments, as always. Thanks

Comment: Joshua, regarding your comment about the lower quality of dbpprop. How do I use dbbpprop only at times when its corresponding dbpedia-owl does not exist . Like this example that dbpedia-owl:title does not exist.

Comment: @user1848018 I don't think there's any automated way to do that.  You'll have to browse the data manually to see what's available.  There's not a one-to-one mapping between dbpprop: and dbpedia-owl: properties.  When you know that both are possible, though, you can write a query that will prefer the dbpedia-owl: property over the dbpprop: property when both are present.